# Error loading Mongrel in Aptana Ruby Application on Vista

Tags: ruby, windows-vista, aptana, mongrel

I'm brand new at Ruby. Trying to set up the first application/project using Aptana Studio.

Here are my ruby and gem versions

```
c:\>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]

c:\>gem -v
1.3.6
```

I am seeing this error below while starting my ruby application. I'm developing on Vista (sucks, I know but am working on changing that)

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/http11.so (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `const_get'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `block in get'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler.rb:17:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/commands/server.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Me - Admin/My Documents/Aptana RadRails Workspace/EventBuzz/script/server:3:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Me - Admin/My Documents/Aptana RadRails Workspace/EventBuzz/script/server:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:2:in `load'
    from -e:2:in `<main>'
```

As a part of fixing this issue, I've installed the following gems and updates

```
c:\>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update

c:\>gem install rails capistrano
mongrel mongrel_cluster Successfully
installed rails-2.3.5 Successfully
installed net-ssh-2.0.21 Successfully
installed net-sftp-2.0.4 Successfully
installed net-scp-1.0.2 Successfully
installed net-ssh-gateway-1.0.1
Successfully installed highline-1.5.2
Successfully installed
capistrano-2.5.18 Successfully
installed mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32
Successfully installed
mongrel_cluster-1.0.5 9 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for
rails-2.3.5... Installing ri
documentation for net-ssh-2.0.21...
Installing ri documentation for
net-sftp-2.0.4... Installing ri
documentation for net-scp-1.0.2...
Installing ri documentation for
net-ssh-gateway-1.0.1... Installing ri
documentation for highline-1.5.2...
Installing ri documentation for
capistrano-2.5.18... Installing ri
documentation for
mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32...
Installing ri documentation for
mongrel_cluster-1.0.5... Updating
class cache with 1380 classes...
Installing RDoc documentation for
rails-2.3.5... Installing RDoc
documentation for net-ssh-2.0.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for
net-sftp-2.0.4... Installing RDoc
documentation for net-scp-1.0.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for
net-ssh-gateway-1.0.1... Installing
RDoc documentation for
highline-1.5.2... Installing RDoc
documentation for capistrano-2.5.18...
Installing RDoc documentation for
mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for
mongrel_cluster-1.0.5...

c:\>gem install mysql Successfully
installed mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32 1
gem installed Installing ri
documentation for
mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32... Updating
class cache with 1641 classes...
Installing RDoc documentation for
mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
```

Ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the support for Ruby 1.9.1 on windows is still not up to scratch yet due to many libraries that contain native extensions is not built for Ruby 1.9.1.

Try using Ruby 1.8.7 on windows, as it has been around for a long time and stable.